# Generalising multiple nested for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, generalization

I have a data structure like this: `map<string, map<string, map<string, MyObj>>>`

Now, I have multiple functions all of which use the same for loop method:

```
for (auto p1 : myMap)
    for (auto p2 : p1.second)
        for (auto p3 : p2.second)
            doThingsWith(p1, p2, 3);
```

Where the `doThingsWith(p1, p2, p3)` varies between functions, as well as the code before and after the for loops. Also, some functions only need to access `MyObj` objects for example, while others need access to all the string keys as well as the `MyObj` objects.

So, the question is, is there any method to generalise this without losing performance? I came up with a function that returns a vector of tuples:

```
vector<tuple<string, string, string, MyObj>> getData(... &myMap)
{
    vector<tuple<string, string, string, MyObj>> data;
    for (auto p1 : myMap)
        for (auto p2 : p1.second)
            for (auto p3 : p2.second)
                data.push_back(tuple<string, string, string, MyObj>(
                    p1.first, p2.first, p3.first, p3.second
                ));
    return data;
}
```

And now my functions can use this:

```
for (auto t : getData(myMap))
    doThingsWith(get<0>(t), get<1>(t), get<2>(t), get<3>(t));
```

But this is unnecessarily constructs *a lot of* tuples and vectors, since `myMap` is huge.

Is there any better way? In Python I can use generators, but I don't know the C++ equilevant:

```
def iterTuples(myMap):
    for k1, v1 in myMap.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                yield k1, k2, k3, v3


for k1, k2, k3, val in iterTuples(myMap):
    doThingsWith(k1, k2, k3, val)
```

Comment: You can define iterator in the same way as Python's generator.

Comment: templated inline recursive functions.

Comment: Maybe try storing `reference_wrapper`s inside tuples? This will avoid copying, but still alow You to get the data inside the tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map-of-maps-of-maps is from the beginning not efficient.  Better would be to consolidate the key parts:

```
typedef tuple<string, string, string> Key;
std::map<Key, MyObj> myMap;
```

Now you have a straightforward efficient solution:

```
for (const auto& pr : myMap)
    doThingsWith(get<0>(pr.first), get<1>(pr.first), get<2>(pr.first), pr.second);
```

And you avoid a lot of indirection.  Even more if you can use fixed-length strings and/or combine the strings into a single allocation.  Or if it's important to share the first and second key strings, you can use a reference-counted string type.

Comment: *"Your map-of-maps-of-maps is from the beginning not efficient."*. Depends if OP has usage with intermediate maps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create template functions:

```
template <typename Map3, typename F>
void ForEachAll(Map3&& m, F&& f)
{
    for (auto&& p1 : m)
        for (auto&& p2 : p1.second)
            for (auto&& p3 : p2.second)
                f(p1.first, p2.first, p3.first, p3.second);
}

template <typename Map3, typename F>
void ForEach(Map3&& m, F&& f)
{
    for (auto&& p1 : m)
        for (auto&& p2 : p1.second)
            for (auto&& p3 : p2.second)
                f(p3.second);
}
```

Note:

- You can name them identically with some SFINAE
- `MAP3` is template to allow const and no const map.